# CI information for sonarqube dashboards

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

We have a centralized Sonarqube setup used by large number of users. Many of the users have used CI set up in non-standard way that now we have many obsolete Sonar dashboards.

Before taking up housekeeping activity to clean up this instance of unused dashboard we need to refer CI jobs publishing these dashboards. But "Continuous integration" link in Dashboard view of Sonarqube is empty in most of the cases. Is there any way (Web UI or backend) to find the details of CI job publishing Sonar dashboard (i,e, for any selected Sonar project I want to get CI job url).

Any thoughts on this from anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your version of SonarQube is 5.6.x, an option is to check HTTP logs contained in the file `logs/access.log`. The analysis reports are sent by scanners to the URL `api/ce/submit` with the project key as a parameter. The logs contain the IP of the scanner machine, if it can help you...

Example of report of project `foo` sent from 127.0.0.1:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jan/2017:17:38:31 +0100] "POST /api/ce/submit?projectKey=foo&projectName=Foo HTTP/1.1" 200 44 "-" "SonarQubeRunner/2.5.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have checked this and it is not of much help for my usecase. As we have hundreds of jobs running in single slave machine exact CI job information would be more appropriate. Is there any plans implement such feature in future.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube does not track any information related to where/how the analysis of a project has been triggered.

So if your projects don't provide the "Continuous Integration" link that is available on the project home page, then SonarQube won't be able to help you on this topic.

Comment: That is very unfortunate. Not even any of the Sonarqube backend logs help us regarding this?

Comment: SonarQube gets analysis reports to digest - wherever they come from. So unfortunately no, there's nothing in the logs that can help.